# Accessing a character from int variable using pointer in C

Tags: c, char, bit-representation

Why the output of below code is -127. Why shouldn't it be -1?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 129;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)&a;
    printf("%d ",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it be 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be understood as follows:

We all know that the range of (signed) `char` is from `[-128 to 127]`, now let's break this range into binary format, so, the bits required is `8` (`1` Byte)

`0`   : `0000 0000`
 `1`   : `0000 0001`
 `2`   : `0000 0010`
 `3`   : `0000 0011`
...
 `126` : `0111 1110`
 `127` : `0111 1111` <-- max +ve number as after that we will overflow in sign bit
`-128` : `1000 0000` <-- *weird number* as the number and its 2's Complement are same.
`-127` : `1000 0001`
`-126` : `1000 0010`
...
`-3`   : `1111 1101`
`-2`   : `1111 1110`
`-1`   : `1111 1111`

---

So, now coming back to the question, we had  `int a = 129;`, clearly `129` when stored inside the `char` data type it is going to overflow as the max positive permissible value is `127`. *But why we got `-127` and not something else?*

Simple, binary equivalent of `129` is `1000 0001` and for `char` data-type that comes somewhere around,

`127` : `0111 1111`
`-128` : `1000 0000`
`-127` : `1000 0001`<-- here!
`-126` : `1000 0010`
...
So, we get `-127` when `129` is stored in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you will output the variable `a` in hexadecimal you will see that it is represented like `0x81`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 129;
    
    printf( "%#x\n", a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0x81
```

`0x80` is the minimal value of an object of the type char if the type char behaves as the type signed char. This value is equal to the decimal value `-128`.

Here is another demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c = -128;
    
    printf( "%#hhx\n", c );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0x80
```

If to add `1` you will get the value `-127`.

The two's complement representation of the character value `-1` looks in hexadecimal like `0xff`. If to add `1` you will get `0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a signed char to int, what will be filled for left 24 bits?
The answer is not always '0', but the 'sign bit' -- highest bit -- .

You may interest the following demo code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 129;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)&a;
    
    // output "0x81", yes  129 == 0x81
    printf("0x%hhx\n",*ptr);


    // output 0xffffff81
    int b = *ptr;   // convert a 'signed char' to 'int'
                    // since the 'sign bit' of the char is 'minus', so left padding that much '1'
    printf("0x%x\n",b);
    
    unsigned char *ptru = (unsigned char *)&a;
    b = *ptru;
    printf("0x%x\n",b);  // still, output "0x81" 

    return 0;
}
```